# Make “Collective Members” table more self-explainatory

Tags: feature-request, collectives

On the page https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/go?tab=members

1. The first column has trophy symbols, that just have the meaning 1st/2nd/3rd. The icons do not add clarity, but the opposite.
   Not obvious how rank is calculated.
2. Top-level user [icza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1705598/icza) has a star icon, that is not clear as to what it is related to and no link to explain the meaning.
3. Top contribution header has (i) icon, but it is not clickable (on iPad Safari)
4. Are badges and reputation relevant to a particular Collective or the total for a user in the specified period?
   It is also initially not clear that the values are only for a specific period.

I understand that you tried to reuse existing users list pages, but in Collectives' context, there are different expectations from the generic list.

Comment: 1. Rank is based on rep gain over the time period selected, this can clearly be seen by looking at the rank column and rep column side by side, 2. The star means recognised member, logo means employee, 3. Repro'd, not clickable on mobile FF, 4. No idea what the badges column is meant to indicate, I don't think it's related to the period at all, as it's the same regardless of period chosen